# JSP Page Imports / Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, jsp

The issue I am having involves server side (JSP) so I can't put together a jFiddle example but I will do my best to demonstrate the issue as simply as I can here:

First, I have a JSP page which at the top of the page I import a javascript file which holds a javascript class that is used a variable amount of times on the page.

So the following (import A) gets imported at the top of the JSP page for use within the page content:

```
<script>
    var TheJSClass = function(aValue, bValue) {
     var me = this;
     this.somePropertyA = aValue;
     this.somePropertyB = bValue;
     this.showValues = function() {
      console.log("me.somePropertyA = " + me.somePropertyA);
      console.log("me.somePropertyB = " + me.somePropertyB);
     }
    }
</script>
```

so on the JSP page there is just some HTML:

```
<ul>

  <li> blah blah blah 
    <!-- jsp import B here -->
  </li>

  <li> blah2 blah2 blah2
    <!-- jsp import B here -->
  </li>

</ul>
```

The following is an example for import B

```
<!-- the unique_id is an attribute set on the page that I increment here at the top of this (import B) file this was my attempt to differentiate between the instances of the class within import A-->
<script>
 var info<%=unique_id%> = new TheJSCLass(10,20);
</script>
<a href="" onclick="info<%=unique_id%>.showValues();">Try Me</a>
```

this all seems to work....The problem happens when I add multiple imports... For example, the following:

```
<!-- Another Import B -->

    <script>
     var info<%=unique_id%> = new TheJSCLass(30,40);
    </script>
    <a href="" onclick="info<%=unique_id%>.showValues();">Try Me</a>
```

and then another:

```
<!-- Another Import B -->

    <script>
     var info<%=unique_id%> = new TheJSCLass(60,70);
    </script>
    <a href="" onclick="info<%=unique_id%>.showValues();">Try Me</a>
```

The problem is, that every "Try Me" button shows the values from the last import, so they will all show 60 70 as the values...  Am I going about this all wrong?  Any advice?  Thanks for everyone's time.

---

EDIT:   I just made this jFiddle which has everything except for JSP adding the number to each variable name and it works fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/vzo4fmjt/

So is it something to do with the JSP number that I am adding to the variable name during each import?

Comment: You should check the markup and see, what variable names are generated. Is it a possibility that `unique_id` never gets updated?

Comment: the unique_id is definitely getting updated, the variable names each have a different number (info0, info1, info2, etc)  I also console.log out the showValues() right after creating each variable and they all output with the correct values, but it seems like as soon as the next imports happen the values are getting overwritten somehow, because no matter which showValues() is run (info0.showValues(), or info2.showValues())  it always outputs the values of the last one that was created.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone who tried to see what was going wrong. It turned out that I was doing something incredibly stupid. In my real file, the "var me = this;" bit was missing var making it global which was causing this...  Sorry to anyone who's time I wasted!